# Self-signed certificate for haproxy causes chrome warning of insecure connection

Tags: ssl-certificate

I try to setup SSL termination with haproxy as a test stand. It serves the test page on 80 port well, but on 443 port chrome shows a warning that ssl connection is not secure and the icon with https stricken through.

I created certificate with these commands:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout web.key -out web.crt
cat web.crt web.key > web.pem
```

with **Common name** defined as `haproxy.com`

Also I put `haproxy.com` to my `/etc/hosts` file

Here is the excerpt of haproxy:

```
frontend  main
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /root/web.pem
    mode http
    default_backend             app

backend app
    balance     roundrobin
    server  app1 127.0.0.1:8080 check
    server  app2 127.0.0.1:8081 check
```

How can I manage this warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A self-signed certificate is not trusted by any browser, as you are the one who signed the certificate and not a certificate authority. You can import the root certificate in the trust store of the browser, but this will only make your connection a trusted one, while others will receive the same warning message.

Answer (score 0):

Even with an **official CA-signed certificate** I got a warning from Chrome for insecure connection until I added the X-Forwarded-Proto setting in my frontend. Simplified example where haproxy is used as localhost SSL front end onto a Tomcat backend listening (no SSL) on port 8080:

```
frontend web_plainhttp
    bind *:80
    redirect prefix https://www.example.com code 301 
frontend web_https
    bind *:443 ssl crt www.example.com_SSLcert.pem
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
    option forwardfor
    default_backend w_website
backend w_website
    server w_server 127.0.0.1:8080
```

just remove the line "http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https" and Chrome shows the connection as insecure... indeed http responses are affected by the backend server returning http or https in headers/content according to the incoming protocol